# Degrees of freedom

Tags: classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom

Consider a system of 10 (say) point particles each at a fixed distance from each other in 3-D space.
In this case, the number of degrees of freedom: $3*(number-of-particle)-\binom{10}{2}=3*10-45<0$
which is wrong as it cannot be negative.
So, is the number of degrees of freedom 6 by considering it a rigid body?
If yes, why does the above formula fail?

Comment: Hint: you're forgetting about the momentum degrees of freedom.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by momentum degrees of freedom @probably_someone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Degree of freedom paradox for a rigid body](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20954/)

Comment: Yes, that answered my question @Paul Kertscher